# Reflection & Transmission curves of waveguides

Tags: optics, waves, electrical-engineering

I have simulated a grating-coupled waveguide in [Comsol Multiphysics](http://www.comsol.com/), the waveguide consists of 2 dielectric layers and air as the cover of waveguide. I have excited the modes of this structure by a plane wave using diode laser (1550 nm). Comsol Multiphysics calculated the reflection and transmission coefficients by scattering parameters and plotted the curves. Do the reflection and transmission curves change by increasing the air layer? I think evanescent wave could not reach the top of the layer and would not affect the curves.

Comment: My guess is: if your original air layer is more than a few wavelengths deep, making it thicker will have zero or nearly zero effect (depending mostly on how many terms in the numerical expansion of the decay curve Comsol carries).

Comment: Dear Mr Witthoft

Comment: I have some problems in analysing these periodic structures that I have simulated in Comsol,I mean the waveguide with grating. I will be grateful if you introduced me to a book about these structures that helps me for Comsol simulation